# How to call Mathematica from $ \rm\LaTeX $?

Tags: front-end, formatting, text, latex

The [`sagetex` package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/?lang=en) for $ \rm\LaTeX $ allows you to embed Sage code into a $ \rm\LaTeX $ document, have that code evaluated during the `.tex` document processing, and then the results — numeric, symbolic, or graphical — from Sage are embedded in the pdf created by $ \rm\LaTeX $.

Is there anything comparable for *Mathematica* instead of Sage?

I *am* aware of the [`MaTeX` package](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) for *Mathematica*, but that does just the opposite of what I'm asking: `MaTeX` allows $ \rm\LaTeX $ typesetting within a *Mathematica* notebook.

Comment: Interesting question. You can also do what you are asking with R through [Sweave and knitr](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552056-Using-Sweave-and-knitr). Two years ago I found the use of [R in LyX documents (through knitr)](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/lyx/) very convenient, but since then I moved to using almost exclusively the [R-Markdown-Pandoc](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html) combination provided by RStudio.

Comment: It is also possible to call python from latex and have the output go into the latex. Here is [example](http://12000.org/my_notes/python_in_latex/index.htm) However, all these methods got it all the wrong way around, and they really do not work at all well in practice. The correct way to do all this is reverse the roles. Generate Latex from the program itself. Not call the program from Latex. Why? Because the Latex environment itself is not suited for using it as the container of such complex tasks. LaTex It is very fragile. Only lua can really be used with Lualatex with ease. IMHO ofcourse :)

Comment: .. what I mean is that if you could find some magic way to call Mathematica from Latex, it will not be practical use and will not scale well....

Comment: Related from TeX.SX: [Automatically generated plots with Mathematica](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144304/70587).

Comment: Is this what you're after? This calls W|A and Wolfram cloud: https://devpost.com/software/alphatex

Comment: AlphaTeX is similar to what I'm after. However, unless I'm mistaken, it seems to call the online service Wolfram Alpha and not the kernel of any local copy of *Mathematica*.

Comment: I've examined the docs that come with alphatex and haven't a clue as to where the package `cloud.m` should be located or how it is loaded.

Comment: And running `pdflatex --shell-escape medoc.tex` with a `\usepackage{latex alpha}` and the body `$\WolframAlpha{biggest city in U.S.}$` causes an error of a missing `$`, with no return from W|A included in the resulting .pdf. (Yes, `curl` is installed on my Mac.)

Answer (score 10):

You can use `Splice`, which has been superseded by `FileTemplate` since v10.

[ As of 12.1 `Splice` has an entirely different meaning! ]

The way it works, although all of the documentation is now gone (except that a tutorial still exists `tutorial/SplicingWolframLanguageOutputIntoExternalFiles`), is that in `<* these kinds of matched star-angle-bracket delimiters *>` you can put Mathematica code.  Then invoke `Splice[input_file, output_file]` (and don't make them the same file!)  In the few times I ever used this I called the file I wrote `[whatever].mma.tex` and the output `[whatever].tex`.  Then run $\LaTeX$ on `[whatever].tex` as usual.

Here is an example file, `example.mma.tex`:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{evanb} 
\title{Splicing in Mathematica} 
\date{\today}
% Set myPath to "/path/to/directory/containing/example.mma.tex"
%   <* myPath = "~/Desktop/mma_splice"; *>

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Here we go testing the splicing ability of Mathematica:

% Set up some variables that Mma sees:
% <* a = 3; b = 4; c = 5; *>
One example of a pythagorean triplet is <*{a,b,c}*> because we see that <*a^2*>+<*b^2*> is equal to <*a^2+b^2*>, which is the square of <*c*>.  That is,
\begin{equation}
 a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}
\end{equation}
corresponds to
\begin{equation}
 <*a*>^{2}+<*b*>^{2} = <*a^2*> + <* b^2 *> = <* c^2 *> = <*c*>^{2}.
\end{equation}
You can also dynamically generate polynomials and otherwise do awesome things.  Here is something that \emph{used} to work but doesn't anymore$\ldots$
% <*poly = x^2 + 4x + 4 *>
My polynomial is $<* poly *>$.  It factors into
\begin{equation}
 <*poly*>=<*Factor[poly]*>.
\end{equation}
But we can make plots programmatically:
%   <* Export[myPath<>"/polyPlot.png",Plot[poly,{x,-3,3}]]; *>
\begin{figure}[htbp]
     \centering
      \includegraphics{polyPlot}
  \caption{A plot of $<*poly*>$.  You can see its zero at <*Union[Select[x/.(Solve[poly==0,x]),-3<#<3&]]*>. \label{}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When, from a notebook I invoke `Splice["~/Desktop/mma_splice/example.mma.tex", "~/Desktop/mma_splice/example.tex"]` I wind up with a plot, `polyPlot.png` (because of my `Export` invocation), and a tex file, `example.tex`:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{evanb} 
\title{Splicing in Mathematica} 
\date{\today}
% For exporting the figure below, set myPath to "/path/to/directory/containing/example.mma.tex"
%   Null

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Here we go testing the splicing ability of Mathematica:

% Set up some variables that Mma sees:
% Null
One example of a pythagorean triplet is List(3,4,5) because we see that 9+16 is equal to 25, which is the square of 5.  That is,
\begin{equation}
 a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}
\end{equation}
corresponds to
\begin{equation}
 3^{2}+4^{2} = 9 + 16 = 25 = 5^{2}.
\end{equation}
You can also dynamically generate polynomials and otherwise do awesome things.  Here is something that \emph{used} to work but doesn't anymore$\ldots$
% 4 + 4*x + Power(x,2)
My polynomial is $4 + 4*x + Power(x,2)$.  It factors into
\begin{equation}
 4 + 4*x + Power(x,2)=Power(2 + x,2).
\end{equation}
But we can make plots programmatically:
%   Null
\begin{figure}[htbp]
     \centering
      \includegraphics{polyPlot}
  \caption{A plot of $4 + 4*x + Power(x,2)$.  You can see its zero at List(-2). \label{}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which can then be run through `pdflatex example.tex` to produce a PDF (which I can't seem to embed here, but imgur uploaded it OK: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tyqx.jpg ).  I also can't get `TeXForm` or anything to work in a way that I expect.  This used to work better, I think?  Anyway, you may be better off learning how to use `FileTemplate`.

Rather than opening a notebook to invoke `Splice`, I would wager you could do it via invoking Mathematica on the command line---shouldn't be too tough.

Comment: I've never used `FileTemplate` but it looks like some similar things can be done.  For example, it looks like it supports `<*expr*>` kind of notation.

Comment: And it may be possible to use `ExportString` rather than `TeXForm`.

Comment: `Splice` is not working for me with *Mathematica* 11.1 (under macOS) with your `example.mma.tex`: no `polyPlot` file is produced when I run the same `Splice` command you showed, and so of course (pdf)LaTeX stops with an error at `\includegraphics{polyPlot}` when I process the output file `example.tex` that `Splice` produced.

Comment: That's weird.  I have `$VersionString`=`"11.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 16, 2017)"`

Comment: Is `example.mma.tex` located in the folder `~/Desktop/mma_splice`?  If not, change `myPath` on the 7th line and try again.

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure what happens if you invoke something like `NotebookDirectory[]` in the spliced file.

Comment: Yes, `example.mma.tex` is in `~/Desktop/mma_splice`. In that source file, you have a comment about setting path. Setting path for *what*?

Comment: And you *do*  get an `example.tex` produced?  The `myPath` variable encodes where where the polyPlot.png will be produced (look at the `Export` of the figure).

Comment: Yes, `example.tex` *is* produced. But when I process it in LaTeX, there is no file `polyPlot.png` in the same folder (or anywhere else).

Comment: Hm.  Then I don't know what to say.  You can try running an `Export` statement from a notebook.  Other than that I'm stumped.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably better off coding your figures/tables/etc. in Mathematica and simply exporting as PDF and $\TeX$. You can use `StringTemplate`, `TeXForm`, `Export` and `ExportString` to generate $\TeX$ input. There's no Mathematica wrapper for $\LaTeX$ that I'm aware of, though you could look into Sage's Mathematica bindings and use those in the aforementioned Sage $\LaTeX$ environment if you're really determined.

Answer (score 4):

You may find this collection of Python scripts useful. It does the job you are asking for -- it allows you to include Mathematica code and output in your LaTeX source. The source and examples can be found at https://github.com/leo-brewin/hybrid-latex

Here is a short example (based on example-01 from the GitHub site)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{mmalatex}

\begin{document}

\section*{Calculus}

\begin{mathematica}
   ans = D[x Sin[x],x]                                         (* mma (ans.501,ans) *)
   ans = D[x Sin[x],x]/.x -> Pi/4                              (* mma (ans.502,ans) *)
   ans = Integrate[2 Sin[x]^2, {x, a, b}]                      (* mma (ans.503,ans) *)
   ans = Integrate[2 Exp[-x^2],{x, 0, Infinity}]               (* mma (ans.504,ans) *)
   ans = HoldForm[Integrate[2 Exp[-x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}]]    (* mma (lhs.504,ans) *)
   ans = Integrate[x^2 + y^2,  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, x}]           (* mma (ans.505,ans) *)
   ans = HoldForm[Integrate[x^2 + y^2,  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, x}]] (* mma (lhs.505,ans) *)
\end{mathematica}

\begin{align*}
   &\mma*{ans.501}\\
   &\mma*{ans.502}\\
   &\mma*{ans.503}\\
   \mma{lhs.504}&=\Mma{ans.504}\\
   \mma{lhs.505}&=\Mma{ans.505}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

And here is a png of the output

[image: output from above latex source]

Comment: Could you please include a short demo in the answer itself?

Comment: I've edited my answer to contain a short example.

Comment: I don't understand the config after installing your files: while my python3 is in /usr/local/bin, trying "pylatex.sh -i example-01" gives 'Traceback error for File "example-01_.py", line 11, in <module> from sympy import * ImportError: No module named sympy". How am I supposed to give access to sympy, as the methods recommended at docs.sympy.org are to use anaconda (which I have installed and which includes sympy) that seems to create a python-related file tree, including the python3 binary, in a different place from /usr/local/bin, namely, in /Applications/anaconda3.

Comment: I'm guessing the your still picking up your non-anaconda environment for python. You can either add /Applications/ananconda3/bin to your $PATH (ahead of any other python) or you could try "pylatex.sh -i example-01 -P/Applications/anaconda3/bin/python3"

Answer (score 3):

I'm no Latex expert; however I have had some success with calling WolframScript from within a Tex document.  The premise of my approach is to execute a script that exports some TeX fragment or an image.  The script is generated in situ, then executed and read at the appropriate point.  I use this approach to generate personalized quizzes for students; I can simply search for and replace the random seed and re-run the document.  It does require that [shell escape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82699/how-to-enable-shell-escape-in-texworks) has been implemented.

```tex
\newcommand{\imwr}{\immediate\write18}
\begin{filecontents*}{temp.wl}
seed = 1211;
SeedRandom[seed];
t = TableForm[{
    {"feedback resistor", 
     RandomChoice[{"0.8", "0.9", "1", "1.1", "1.2"}] <> " MOhm"},
    {"internal resistance of phototube", 
     RandomChoice[{"3", "4", "5"}] <> " x10^4 Ohm"},
    {"amplifier open-loop gain", 
     RandomChoice[{"0.9", "1.0", "1.1"}] <> " x10^5"}
    }];
Export["wlout.tex", t, "TexFragment"];
\end{filecontents*}

\imwr {wolframscript -file temp.wl}

\input{wlout}
```