# How to use Mathematica code in LaTeX files?

Tags: latex, scripting, external-calls, code

How can you use Mathematica code in LaTeX files?

any similar to

A random number is RNUMBER and the square of RNUMBER is RNUMBER^2

appearing numbers instead the capital letters (or Mathematica code) in the PDF compiled from .tex

Similar to from the next LaTeX Code obtain the red numers instead the "Mathematica Code"

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\begin{document}

{\Large{\LaTeX\; and Wolfram Mathematica or any other language -r, python- if Mathematica is not possible.}}\\

Hello, this is a random number between $\textbf{nmin}$ and $\textbf{nmax}$: $\textbf{random number}$\\

The previous number was randomly selected from the list:

\textbf{For[i = 1, i $\leq$ nmax, i++, Print[i]]}\\

The square of the selected number is \textbf{RandomInteger[{nmin, nmax}]}$^2$\\

The solution of the ecuation $x=\dfrac{x+21}{7-2x}$ is

\textbf{Solve[x == (x + 20)/(2 + x), x]}\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This was asked before. [how-to-call-mathematica-from-rm-latex](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151567/how-to-call-mathematica-from-rm-latex). Wrong approach IMHO. Do it the otherway around. Use Mathematica and generate the Latex from inside Mathematica as it runs. I do not think it is possible to do what you want (i.e. call mathematica from Latex) and if there is a way, it will be hopelessly complicated and not useful in real life to use.

Comment: I can show you how to do all the above from inside Mathematica, and obtain a complete Latex file at the end. But this is not what you are asking.

Comment: You can use `python` from inside `Latex`, but that is also a bit complicated, but doable. see [this](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/python_in_latex/index.htm) as an example for python. But the easiest way, (if you want to call something from Latex to do some computation) is to use `lua` from inside Latex. `lua` is build into `lualatex`. So no external environment is needed. Using `luacode` package in latex allows you to do this very easily. You can ask at tex stackexchange if need more help on this.

Comment: If your problem is more generally generating the kind of document LaTeX lets you generate, try TeXmacs: https://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/home/welcome.en.html . It's not technically LaTeX, it's a bit more general (though it allows LaTeX-like input), and imo is the closest thing to a modern math text editor. I think there's a mathematica plugin available, which would let you start mathematica sessions inline, in documents, as you want to. There are definitely python and R plugins available. Worth checking out even if it's not useful for this in particular—plus, it's GNU-licensed/open-source! :)